# How to merge the product.id with the req.body.categories into an array of string

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, mongoose

```
const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 categories:  [{
   type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
   ref: 'Category'
  }]
});
```

`How do I generate an array like the following?`

```
{
"categories":["5cd295fbc53f626fd9d70894","5cb0624945111f1c5fdf2527","5cc290f5b90fc527c1e46efd"]
}
```

When i use postman input using raw.json it can successfully push in but if i use urlencoded form input

```
categories:5cd295fbc53f626fd9d70894
categories:5cb0624945111f1c5fdf2527
categories:5cc290f5b90fc527c1e46efd
```

it only push the last id to the array

Comment: thanks you im still newbie in coding thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

The [`express.urlencoded`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded) middelware handles repeated arguments:

```js
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}), function(req, res) {
  res.end(req.body);
});
```

With this, the request

```
POST /server/path
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

categories=A&categories=B
```

returns

```json
{"categories":["A","B"]}
```

Comment: How do i map the each categories into and push each id into the categories fields